# AngularJS $compile act synchronously for use with an API?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, compilation, synchronous, selectize.js

I am attempting to use a library that takes in a string that represents a html element and uses that to render the element dynamically as part of a drop down, however this library assumes that you are using javascript to do so. I am attempting to wrap this library in an angular directive but I'm unsure how to do so with $compile. My problem is as follows.

The library I am using takes an object and uses it to determine how to render the element. The suggested javascript implementation is:

```
render: {
    item: function(item) {
        return '<div><span>' + item.firstName + '</span></div>';
    }
```

I however, would like to use the contents of a template and then compile that as a way to make this more angular-esk. I have the following:

```
render: {
    item: function(item) {
        $scope.item = item;
        var things = jQuery($templateCache.get('testingTemplate.modal.nested'));
        var $el = $compile(things)($scope);
        $timeout(() => {
          return $el.prop('outerHTML');
        }).then(function(working) {
          return working;
        });
        console.log($el);
        return $el;
    }
```

The obvious issue I have encountered with this code is that the value of $el is undefined, as the promise has not complete at this point, and as such nothing is rendered to the DOM. Is there a way to make $compile work synchronously or another way I can do this so that I can use a template and convert that to the proper html representation?

**SOLVED**

I have solved this in the following way for anyone stumbling on this in the future. Please excuse the poorly named variables.

```
 render: {
    item: function(item, escape) {
        $scope.item = item;
        var randomUnique = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        var things = jQuery("<div class='" + randomUnique  +  "'>" + $templateCache.get('testingTemplate.modal.nested') + "</div>");
        var $compiledEl = $compile(things)($scope);
        $timeout(() => {
          var placeHolder = jQuery('.' + randomUnique);
          placeHolder.replaceWith($compiledEl.prop('outerHTML'));
        });
        var hello = (things.prop('outerHTML'));
        return hello;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `$el` is `undefined`? What are the error messages in the console?

Comment: In general the `$compile` service will synchronously link diirectives to scope as long as none of the directives use `templateURL`. Because template loading is asynchronous the compiler will suspend compilation of directives on that element for later when the template has been resolved. In the meantime it will continue to compile and link sibling and parent elements as though this element had not contained any directives. Directives that bind scope to the DOM will need a digest cycle.

Comment: @georgeawg No errors. but the console log before the $el prints undefined. Thank you for the second post, does that mean that it is more than likely the templateCache causing the issues here?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Since most directives that bind scope to DOM need a digest cycle, and the  `$digest` operation is asynchronous, it is unlikely that a library function that operates on a string will work. You would get a better answer if you would tell us which library you are trying to integrate with AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, though maybe not the best, it works. Please ignore the poorly named variables.

```
 render: {
    item: function(item, escape) {
        $scope.item = item;
        var randomUnique = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        var things = jQuery("<div class='" + randomUnique  +  "'>" + $templateCache.get('testingTemplate.modal.nested') + "</div>");
        var $compiledEl = $compile(things)($scope);
        $timeout(() => {
          var placeHolder = jQuery('.' + randomUnique);
          placeHolder.replaceWith($compiledEl.prop('outerHTML'));
        });
        var hello = (things.prop('outerHTML'));
        return hello;
    }
}
```